# Rails: How do I submit multiple objects into strong params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a goal tracking app. Right now outcome, purpose, action, priority, resources, and direction are all things which are part of Outcome in the database. However, I want to make purpose and action their own model objects. What I am confused about is how do I submit Outcome, Purpose, and Action, which will be 3 separate model objects, in a single HTTP request?

Should I just use multiple strong params in my controller?

**app/view/outcomes/new.html.erb**
[image: app/view/outcomes/new.html.erb]

Comment: Are the objects associated in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have model associations of `outcomes` with `purpose` and `action`.

Then you will need to create nested form. So that `outform` form can wrap `purpose` and `action` model attributes.

As you want to have different models for `actions` and `purposes`, I'm assuming `outcome` can `has_many purposes` and `has_many actions`. As per this type of association, below is the code you should have.

Your form will become something like:

```
<%= form_for @outcome do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :outcome, "Outcome" %>
  <%= f.text_area :outcome %>

  <%= f.fields_for :purpose, @outcome.purpose.build do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_area :desc, label: "Purpose" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :action, @outcome.action.build do |p| %>
    <%= p.text_area :desc, label: "Action" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Models:

```
# outcome.rb
has_many :purposes, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :actions, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_of :purposes, :actions

-----------------------------------------

# purpose.rb
belongs_to :outcome

-----------------------------------------

# action.rb
belongs_to :outcome
```

Controller:

```
# outcomes_controller.rb
def outcome_params
    params.require(:outcome).permit(:outcome, purpose_attributes:[:desc], action_attributes: [:desc])
end
```

**SUGGESTION**:  You should rename your `action` model name to avoid unwanted conflicts with rails keyword `action`.

This may [**help**](http://iroller.ru/blog/2013/10/14/nested-model-form-in-rails-4/) you

Answer (score 1):

**Nestd Attributes**

If the objects are associated (as below), you'll be best using the [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) method:

```
#app/models/outcome.rb
Class Outcome < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :purposes
   has_many :actions

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :purposes, :actions
end

#app/models/purpose.rb
Class Purpose < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :outcome
end 

#app/models/action.rb
Class Action < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :outcome
end
```

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` means you'll be able to send the *associated* objects *through* the `Outcome` model - meaning you can send them all in a single HTTP request

You have to remember the way Rails is set up ([MVC pattern](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/MVC-Process.svg/500px-MVC-Process.svg.png)), meaning if you send a single request; any further model objects you have will be able to be stored too.

Here's how you can set it up:

```
#app/controllers/outcomes_controller.rb
Class OutcomesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @outcome = Outcome.new
      @outcome.purposes.build
      @outcoe.actions.build
   end

   def create
      @outcome = Outcome.new(outcome_params)
      @outcome.save
   end

   private

   def outcome_params
       params.require(:outcome).permit(:outcome, purpose_attributes:[:purpose], action_attributes: [:action])
   end
end
```

Which will give you the ability to use this form:

```
#app/views/outcomes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @outcome do |f| %>

   <%= f.label :outcome %>
   <%= f.text_area :outcome %>

   <%= f.fields_for :purposes do |p| %>
      <%= p.text_area :purpose %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.fields_for :actions do |a| %>
      <%= a.text_area :action %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

--

**Recommendation**

From the looks of it, I'd recommend you'll be able to keep all of these details in a **single model** - storing in multiple models seems overkill